# Problems getting django to work on apache with wsgi. Gets a internal server error page

Tags: python, django, installation, mod-wsgi, wsgi

Both Django and wsgi are installed, yet I get a internal server error page when browsing the path.

I have created a project on django named hello..

> /sites-available/hello

```
ServerName hello.djangoserver
DocumentRoot /srv/www/hello

<Directory /srv/www/hello>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess hello.djangoserver processes=2 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP}
WSGIProcessGroup hello.djangoserver

WSGIScriptAlias / /srv/www/hello/apache/django.wsgi
```

/srv/www/hello/apache/apche.wsgi

```
import os
import sys
path = '/srv/www'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.insert(0, '/srv/www')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'hello.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

I'm not getting what problem i'm facing when I open it in browser.

Comment: as a complete stab in the dark ... if you JUST deployed you might need a 500.html template

Comment: Do you really have the configuration `WSGIScriptAlias / /srv/www/hello/apache/django.wsgi` and a file called `/srv/www/hello/apache/apche.wsgi`?